# Nested UI Accordions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using [Jquery UI Accordion](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Here is the html structure

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-section">
     <div class="accordion-head">
     </div>
     <div class="accordion-body">
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="accordion-section">
     <div class="accordion-head">
     </div>
     <div class="accordion-body">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And here is the JS call

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
    header: ".accordion-head",
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```

Now, this works fine until I nest accordion within accordion. When you click on the nesting accordions, the parent accordion closes...

What am I doing wrong? I can nest Tabs, why can't I nest accordions?

**I have put a JS fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mktmapyu/**

Comment: have you tried giving the accordions different classes and having two calls to `.accordion()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
    header: ">.accordion-head", //Note the selector change
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```

instead of

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
    header: ".accordion-head",
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/mktmapyu/3/

**Explanation:** When you pass ".accordion-head" it means that all the elements with class ".accordion-head" will work as header for the accordion. But when you pass ">.accordion-head" then it will set the immediate child with class ".accordion-head" for header and hence the toggling will work only for the corresponding accordions.

Comment: Sorry I should of said, each accordion set is wrapped around an .accordion-section so .accordion then .accordion-sections and then inside each of those there is accordion-head and body

Comment: It will hardly matter. It would be more clear if you can share that html